# Is there a way to stay signed into GitHub for VS Code on Mac?

Tags: macos, github, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I find the 'Sign in to use GitHub Copilot' toast notification pop up every time I start VS Code. I click the link and it authenticates immediately, but I am wondering if there is a way to store my authentication.

My GitHub authentication log looks like this before I click the sign in button.

```
2023-07-03 15:58:02.481 [info] Reading sessions from keychain...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.481 [info] Getting sessions for user:email...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.481 [info] Getting sessions for all scopes...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.481 [error] Getting token failed: Error: Unable to parse decrypted password
2023-07-03 15:58:02.481 [info] Got 0 sessions for user:email...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.482 [info] Got 0 sessions for ...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.482 [info] Reading sessions from keychain...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.567 [info] Getting sessions for read:user,repo,user:email,workflow...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.567 [info] Got 0 sessions for read:user,repo,user:email,workflow...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.658 [info] Getting sessions for read:user...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.659 [info] Got 0 sessions for read:user...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.668 [info] Getting sessions for read:user,repo,user:email...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.668 [info] Got 0 sessions for read:user,repo,user:email...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.692 [info] Getting sessions for user:email...
2023-07-03 15:58:02.692 [info] Got 0 sessions for user:email...
```

Any ideas how to stay signed in? I don't have any issues using VS Code + Copilot in this way on my work computer (Windows).

Additionally, it would be nice for settings sync to remember my GitHub selection.

I've looked through a few reccomendations. Do I need to create a personal access token?

Comment: Reported at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76607861/is-there-a-way-to-stay-signed-into-github-for-vs-code-on-mac